# Alloy UI checkbox return datatype

Tags: jsp, user-interface, checkbox, liferay, alloy-ui

If am writing this below mentioned code in my jsp file along with alloy UI, what data type I will be receiving in my Java class as a response.

And what code I have to write to retrieve my selections ?

```
    <%
            for (Manufacturer manufacturer : manufacturers) {
        %>
        <aui:input type="checkbox" name="location"
            value="<%=manufacturer.getManufacturerId()%>"
            label="<%=manufacturer.getName()%>"/>
        <%
            }
        %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `String[] locationValues = ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "locationCheckbox");` can get checked values.

Here is the test result (assume you checked Manufacturer A and Manufacturer C):

view.jsp:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="actionURL" name="myAction" />

<aui:form action="<%=actionURL %>">
    <aui:input type="checkbox" id="a123" label="Manufacturer A" name="location" value="a123"></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="checkbox" id="b456" label="Manufacturer B" name="location" value="b456"></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="checkbox" id="c789" label="Manufacturer C" name="location" value="c789"></aui:input>
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Submit"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

Testing Java code:

```
public void myAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response){
    Enumeration<String> params = request.getParameterNames();
    while (params.hasMoreElements() )
    {
        String para_name = (String)params.nextElement();
        if(para_name.startsWith("location")){
            System.out.println(para_name);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("location-getString:" + ParamUtil.getString(request, "location"));
    System.out.println("location-getParameterValues:" + Arrays.toString(ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "location")));

    System.out.println("locationCheckbox-getString:" + ParamUtil.getString(request, "locationCheckbox"));
    System.out.println("locationCheckbox-getParameterValues:" + Arrays.toString(ParamUtil.getParameterValues(request, "locationCheckbox")));
}
```

Console result:

```
location
locationCheckbox
location-getString:a123
location-getParameterValues:[a123, b456, c789]
locationCheckbox-getString:a123
locationCheckbox-getParameterValues:[a123, c789]
```

Notes:
I test the above codes with Liferay 6.2.  It creates two input fields to client side for each `<aui:input type="checkbox" ... />`:

```
<input type=hidden name="<portlet:namespace/>location" ... />
<input type=checkbox name="<portlet:namespace/>locationCheckbox" ... />
```

Further Action:
If you would like set pre-checked values, add the following sample code to doView function:

```
List<String> preCheckedLocation = new ArrayList<String>();
preCheckedLocation.add("a123");
preCheckedLocation.add("c789");
renderRequest.setAttribute("preCheckedLocation",preCheckedLocation);
```

add `checked=true|false` to `<aui:input>` field in view.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>

...

<%
    List<String> preCheckedLocation = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("preCheckedLocation");
%>

...

<aui:form action="<%=actionURL %>">
    <aui:input type="checkbox" id="a123" label="Manufacturer A" name="location" value="a123" checked='<%= preCheckedLocation.contains("a123") %>' ></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="checkbox" id="b456" label="Manufacturer B" name="location" value="b456" checked='<%= preCheckedLocation.contains("b456") %>' ></aui:input>
    <aui:input type="checkbox" id="c789" label="Manufacturer C" name="location" value="c789" checked='<%= preCheckedLocation.contains("c789") %>' ></aui:input>
    <aui:button type="submit" value="Submit"></aui:button>
</aui:form>
```

Comment: That's a nice explanation but do you know how to precheck the checkboxes.
I mean if I have an edit selection page in which we have to show users their previous slection.

Comment: Yes, change the attribute of checked to "Yes" once the value contains in the String Array.  I am testing the code.

Comment: @HarshalShah I amended my answer.